# Extension methods & dynamic vars

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, extension-methods

Is there a reason for dynamic variables to not support extension methods? Is there a way to circumvent that?

Here is an exemple:

I don't forgot the using directive of the class holding the extension method i'm using:

```
using System.Linq;
```

This code works without problem:

```
IEnumerable<string> ie = new HashSet<string>() { "test" };
Console.WriteLine(ie.ToList()[0]);
```

This one throw an exception:

```
IEnumerable<string> ie = new HashSet<string>() { "test" };
Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)ie).ToList()[0]);
```

> ''System.Collections.Generic.HashSet' does not contain a definition for 'ToList''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToList` from Linq expects a **compile-time**-`IEnumerable`. By using `dynamic` you completely hide the compile-time-type and make it impossible for the compiler to infer the right method. So you rely on runtime-binding.

Now an extension-method is just syntactic sugar for a `static` method:

```
static class Enumerable
{
    public static List<T> ToList(IEnumerable<T> e) { ...}
}
```

which you would call like this:

```
Enumerable.ToList(myHashSet);
```

This is what the compiler does also. It translates all calls to `hashSet.ToList()` into `Enumerable.ToList(hashSet)`.

This method has nothing to do with your actual class - the hashset - because extension-methods don't **modify** existing classes. They just define methods that **seem** like if they were added to the class. Or in other words: at runtime - this is when `dynamic` is evaluated - there is no such method `HashSet.ToList`, but `Enumerable.ToList`.

Comment: That means, if I have to deal with a dynamic, I can't use the extention methods (other than casting the dynamic to a IEnumerable<dynamic>)?

Comment: @Sébastien Well, to be honest I would try to avoid `dynamic` as far as possible. In fact I really really seldomly have any need for that.

Comment: I do it as much as possible too, but I'm working on a template parser that convert variables in a Word doc with the value of those vars in the app. I.e.: [Path.To.My.Array[0].Property] = the value of "Property" in the first object of the enumerable "Path.To.My.Array". Where Property can be an int, string..., Array can be an array, a List or whatever IEnumerable and {Path, To, My} are objets. So, to be the most abstract as possible and not deal with every possibilities, I have to use dynamic vars.

Comment: @Sébastien Not neccessarily. What about casting to `ICollection` or even `IList`? They also provide index-based access.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'll do, this is just to explain why I had to deal with dynamic vars (at least to fetch the values of the corresponding vars), because I can't know in advance what is the type of the var I'm fetching.